# How to use Angular ChangeDetectionStrategy to make a table with multiple inputs faster?

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I have an Angular application with a table that contains over 200 rows with 10 inputs each. If I go to the last page and add some text to an input it works fine, but if a go to the last page pressing tab and editing the values, it starts getting slow.

It isn't a network problem, I already have all the data on the screen. The problem is when I pass over all the inputs changing values, as more I change slower it gets to type in the input, like it is lagging.

I tried adding `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in my component and it got faster, but I have to click on the screen to render the table for the first time. Also, I noticed that searching in the table fields got a lot slower.

Is there any way to force the application to refresh the change detection only for the currently displayed inputs?

I used chrome Devtools as sugested, and you can see the response increases over time with keydowns, as I edit the values of inputs of the table.
[image: Recorded performance with chrome DevTools]

[image]

Comment: You haven't provided the details. Have you figured out what causes the lag (e.g. JS, network)? Are you using some commercial table, or have written the code yourself. Angular is quite optimized by itself, if you are doing things correctly - it does not need any change-detection manipulations.

Comment: people can only help you improve your code if you show what you’re doing. There is a lot that can be done but performance tuning is quite complex and case specific. There isn’t a magic multi tool

Comment: "only for the currently displayed inputs" sounds like `overflow:auto`. Think about virtualization and render only the visible elements. Angular CDK can help you with this: https://material.angular.io/cdk/categories

Comment: Sorry, guess I shoud be more specific. I'm going to update the question. But it isn't slow requests to the database or slow connection, I already have all the data on screen, the problem is when I pass over all the inputs changing values. It gets slow to type in the input, like the change event is checking all the other inputs of the table.

Comment: Zoom in into the areas that grow on the graph. It show what exact function is called. Most likely you are running some code for each loop (row/cell). *Make sure to remove any console.log/debug* statements - running those 200 times in loop can crash your browser.

Comment: I updated the description with the image.

Comment: You need to focus on `KeyUp`, `KeyDown` functions: 1) Why those are triggered so often, what calls them? 2) What is inside each function - it seems to take time to process.

Answer (score 2):

In order to improve the performance one first needs to figure out - *what causes the lag.*

### Dev Tool Performance

1. Use [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools) (or any other similar tool) to record and measure the performance on the page. Example output:

[image]

2. Determine what causes the problem. Is it a slow JavaScript execution? Is it a network problem.
3. Fix it accordingly.

---

JavaScript-related problem can be caused by a number of reasons. May be you are running some code in a loop and it causes extra calculations.

What table are you using. Is a a [Material Table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview), see the tools to improve the performance (like pagination). If you are dealing with thousands of records, consider using Data Grids (e.g. [Ag Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/)).

### Example

Watch this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5fLW5Q5ODiE) for a clear demo of how to improve the load time.

Comment: I updated the question with an image of the performance. The response time is getting slow. I think the check for changes is being applied to all the inputs that changed.

Comment: Provide the code which can apply the check (if you do it manually). Again, Angular should handle hundreds of rows without lags - see this example where Angular Material shows 10000 rows using a virtual-scroll: https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview#creating-items-in-the-viewport.